# JavaScript Unexpected Quantifier Error in Internet Explorer, but works in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The following code snippet is causing Internet Explorer to throw an Unexpected Quantifier error, but Google chrome is working just fine.

`var regexWord = new RegExp("\\b(?<!-)"+lWord+"\\b(?!-)");`

How to fix this so it works cross browser?

**UPDATE**

After some testing it appears the error is a result of `(?<!-)` in the regex pattern. Though, still not sure how to fix it. Seems like it is correct based on the regex documentations I've read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only Google Chrome supports lookbehind `?<!`

So replacing `(?<!-)` with `[^-]` should do the trick.

Comment: It works but it does not give same result. The part you wish to lookbehind is included in [^-] so you need to remove that after the match to get same result.